# Can i use Oracle No sql database on a android app

Tags: android, sql, performance, oracle-nosql

Pretty straight forward developing a android app and instead of using a relation database i want to use a graph database any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: You can use a client-server architecture with the client being an Android device and the database hosted on a centrally-accessible server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO. Android uses light weight database SQlite for Dalvik virtual machines (mobiles) . The Room jetpack component is an abstraction layer over SQlite and optimised to use instead of simple sqlite ,it helps in compile time query validation, keep app with latest data changes and data caching. However you could use remote db such as firebase/firestore(no SQL) based as backend db for your app.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. What kind of DB would you recommend for  multiple users at once and scaling up for more users easily in the future. I am going to create a server for the database so users can access it over  the internet? thank you